# `loop{}` versus `loop{sleep 1}`

Tags: ruby, multithreading, performance, loops

I am using a loop to wait on a keyboard interrupt and then allow for some clean up operation before exit in a multi threaded environment.

```
begin
  loop {}
rescue Interrupt
  p "Ctr-C Pressed..Cleaning Up & Shutting Down"
  loop do
    break if exit_bool.false?
  end
  exit 130
end
```

This piece of code runs in the main thread. There are multiple threads performing several file and DB ops. `exit_bool` is an atomic var set by other threads to indicate they are in the middle of some operation. I check for the value and wait until it turns `false` and then exit.

I'm wondering what the cost of `loop{}` is as opposed to `loop{sleep x}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`loop {}` results in a high CPU utilization (~100%), whereas `loop { sleep x }` does not.

Another option is to just [`sleep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) forever:

```
begin
  sleep
rescue Interrupt
  # ...
end
```